# How do redirection in a symbols work in a sequence?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I have file1, file2, file3.

---

file1 contains `1`

file2 contains `2`

file3 contains `3`

I use command

`cat file1 > file2 > file3`

Results in:

file1 `1`

file2  (contains nothing)

file3 `1`

---

Why does anything along this line get destroyed? Basically what am I not seeing behind the scenes?

(Side notes using "append" `>>` is even weirder)

Comment: Check out Muru's answer below if you want an answer on how the command actually functions on a lower level!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Redirections in Bourne/POSIX-style shells [such as bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections), dash, ksh, etc.

> processed in the order they appear, from left to right

`> x` [opens *and truncates*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Output) file `x`, and sets the file descriptor that writes into `x` as standard output. Your command:

```
cat file1 > file2 > file3
```

Will:

1. Open and truncate `file2`
2. Set standard output to write to that file descriptor
3. Open and truncate `file3`
4. Set standard output to write to that file descriptor
5. Run `cat file1`

The end result is that standard output points into `file3` at the time `cat` runs. Both `file2` and `file3` have their current contents erased, and `file3` gets the output of `cat` (the contents of `file1`) written into it.

---

If you want to split output into multiple streams written into separate files, you can [use `tee`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html):

```
cat file1 | tee file2 > file3
```

---

Other shells ([notably `zsh`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios)) behave differently, and your command would have the result you probably expected: both `file2` and `file3` would have the contents of `file1`.

---

Note that `cat` isn't necessary here; `<` input redirection would do the job just as well.

Comment: I wish I could accept both your answer and @muru as for zsh it does do it the way I expected originally.

Comment: While `cat` may not be necessary, _some_ command that reads from the input file is.  `< inputfile > outputfile` will just truncate the output file, it won't copy the input file to it.

Comment: It's a preemptive [UUOC](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html) ward for the `tee` command. `< x > y` actually does work in `zsh`, though.

Comment: I remember alta vista . . (link contains reference to alta vista) It almost seems like a formula would work here to explain the interaction, like it must be every other `> or <` must be opposite to keep the data flowing. But I really don't know for sure and too tired to think.

Answer (score 9):

When you redirect an fd multiple times, all redirections get performed, and the last one sticks:

```
$ strace -f -e open bash -c 'cat file1 > file2 > file3'
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
...
[pid 20508] open("file2", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
[pid 20508] open("file3", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
...
[pid 20508] open("file1", O_RDONLY)     = 3
```

So, `file2` was opened and truncated, and then `file3` was opened.

Comment: so this actually runs the command through as it would be through c ?

Comment: @NoTime if you're talking of strace, it runs the command the way it normally runs, but lists the system calls made. Those can be made in any language that the system api is available in. Strace is like a debugger in that respect.

Comment: That is awesome, that would probably have answered my question more or less right there. So the basically it's like setting a variable 200 times, it really doesn't matter what the first 199 were. (Just me trying to do analogy for myself)

Comment: @NoTime yes, that's how I see it too. And that's why zsh's behaviour, while certainly more useful, strikes me as counterintuitive.

Comment: I think your answer is great. I am not sure it will be useful to as many people,(it was super effective for me) so I didn't accept it (sorry). But I upvoted one of your other great questions.

Comment: @NoTime no problem. I would have accepted Homer's answer too. Thanks for the upvote. :)