# Why output is on the prompt line?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, output

```
$ echo 'hello world' > >(wc)
$     1    2    12
█
```

Why output is on the **prompt line** and not in the separate line below?
Also why expects input at the end?

Since, the command below works fine as expected.

```
$ ls -l > >(wc)
     32     288    2120
$
```

Please elaborate the case of **echo** command. And others in general.

Comment: What version of the `bash` shell do you have. Output appears in a separate line on GNU bash 4.2.45

Comment: what is `And others in general.`?

Comment: the output is on the prompt line because it is programmed to be that way .... if you want the output on the next line, then insert the newline character

Comment: why output on prompt line even necessary? Also where to add newline character to fix it.

Comment: I can replicate this on versions 4.3.42 and 4.4.12 of the Bourne Again shell.  The Z shell does the right thing, in contrast.  For extra fun with these versions of the Bourne Again shell, try running the command in the background.  That results in the output of `wc` never appearing at all.

Comment: is there anything wrong with just piping it instead? `echo "hello world" | wc` will show on a new line

Answer (score -1):

`echo` is a builtin command, `ls` is an external command.
Use `type echo` and `type ls` to find which is which.

Comment: Neither of which is relevant, as the output in the question comes from `wc`, which _should_ have run to completion by the time that the Bourne Again shell issues the prompt.  I suspect a Bourne Again shell bug where it does not properly wait for processes spawned by process substitution.